# unused @Composable function check in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I accidentally closed [unused @Composable function check] in Android Studio.
Now my Android Studio no longer check the @composable function used or not.
How to re-enable it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7wof.png)

I search the setting and didn't find something work.